# Problem updating Georeferencing for TIFF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, update

When I update georeferencing for TIFFs, the map disappears and doesn't save. Auto adjust is off, rectify wont save, control points I can save seperately. Settings are set to documentation suggestions. How can I update and save these images? My workflow goes as follows:

Add data(tiff file), asked if I want to create pyramids to which I agree, fit to display, use 2-3 control points to line up, then I usually update processing, but I tried to rectify and it pops up saying failed to save even though the .ovr file has been created and in the same location as original TIFF. I was on the phone with Esri yesterday who said all I needed to do was turn off auto-fit (which I did and update geoprocessing actually worked!) but now today I am back at the same issue. I have also restarted computer/cleared cache several times

Comment: It does create pyramids when I add the image to ArcMap

Comment: Could you please highlight the exact steps you took to do the georeferencing?

Comment: It would be best to edit your question with the information in your comments.

Comment: Perhaps check "world" file in options, raster.